# SQL Subquery with aggregate function - seeking alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, pivot, window-functions

My table (Table1)

```
+----+------------+---------+------------+
| id |    Date    |  Houses | kW_measure |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
| 01 | 01/01/2020 | House_A |    2020    |
| 02 | 01/01/2020 | House_B |    2100    |
| 03 | 01/01/2020 | House_C |    2200    |
| 04 | 01/02/2020 | House_A |    2040    |
| 05 | 01/02/2020 | House_B |    2125    |
| 06 | 01/02/2020 | House_C |    2210    |
| 07 | 01/03/2020 | House_A |    2050    |
| 08 | 01/03/2020 | House_B |    2150    |
| 09 | 01/03/2020 | House_C |    2220    |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
```

I did a sort of Pivot and it's fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45b9d/1/0

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|    Date    |  House_A |  House_B |  House_C |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/01/2020 |   2020   |   2100   |   2200   |
| 01/02/2020 |   2040   |   2125   |   2210   |
| 01/03/2020 |   2050   |   2150   |   2220   |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now I need to calculate the difference between measures, to get something like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
|    Date    |  House_A | Daily |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 01/01/2020 |   2020   |   0   |
| 01/02/2020 |   2040   |   20  |
| 01/03/2020 |   2050   |   10  |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

But if I don't use an aggregate, the result brings me null cells - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45b9d/5/0

```
SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT a.Date)
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.Houses = 'House_A' THEN a.kW_measure END) as 'House_A'
, a.Kw_Measure - (SELECT MIN(b.kW_Measure) FROM Table1 b WHERE b.Houses = 'House_A'
     AND b.Date < a.Date)

FROM Table1 a

GROUP BY Date, kW_Measure
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

And if I do use it, I get the message:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Derived tables or CTEs are a way to get aggregates of aggregates also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions. Starting from your existing conditional aggregation query, this computes the consumption difference between the current and previous date for each house:

```
select
    date,
    house_a,
    coalesce(house_a - lag(house_a) over(order by date), 0) daily_a,
    house_b,
    coalesce(house_b - lag(house_b) over(order by date), 0) daily_b,
    house_c,
    coalesce(house_c - lag(house_c) over(order by date), 0)daily_c
from (
    select 
        date, 
        sum(case when houses = 'House_A' then kw_measure end) as house_a,
        sum(case when houses = 'House_B' then kw_measure end) as house_b,
        sum(case when houses = 'House_C' then kw_measure end) as house_c
    from table1
    group by date
) t
order by date
```

The subquery is not technically necessary, but it avoids repeating the conditional `sum()`s twice.

Comment: That's the cleanest solution, with the subquery

Answer (score 1):

If you want the house as a separate column as the results suggest, you can just use:

```
select house, date, kw_measure,
       (kw_measure -
        lag(kw_measure, 1, kw_measure) over (partition by house order by date) 
       ) as diff
from table1;
```

You only seem to have one row per house per date, so aggregation doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Also a good solution if I don't have to use each house as a column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag`, here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45b9d/15).

```
with cte as
(
  select
    distinct date,
    houses,
    kW_measure,
    lag(kW_measure) over (partition by houses order by date) as last_value
  from table1
)

select
  date,
  coalesce(sum(case when houses = 'House_A' then kW_measure - last_value end), 0) as House_A,
  coalesce(sum(case when houses = 'House_B' then kW_measure - last_value end), 0) as House_B,
  coalesce(sum(case when houses = 'House_C' then kW_measure - last_value end), 0) as House_C
from cte
group by
  date
order by
  date
```

Output:

```
| date       | house_a | house_b | house_c |
| -----------| ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0       | 0       | 0       |
| 2020-01-02 | 20      | 25      | 10      |
| 2020-01-03 | 10      | 25      | 10      |
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but since I had to use both House_n and Daily_n, the code got bigger for me.